# Error message when trying to boot up Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04

I have just upgraded from 17.10 to 18.04 LTS. When I try to boot up Ubuntu I get the following error message

> 'Gtk-WARNING **:cannot open display'

and I can't access Ubuntu at all. I have never had a problem like this with any previous versions of Ubuntu.
Can anybody advise please?
My present computer is a dual-boot with Windows 10.

Comment: Did you use xorg in 17.10?

Comment: I don't believe I did. I tried to install Wine in 17.10 and it caused me some problems

Comment: Can you access to another tty? (press Ctr+Alt+F3)